# How can I fetch the next level of the currently selected main menu (hierarchical menu)?

Tags: themes, menus

I have the following structure (defined at Appearance > Menu):

- foo

  - fii
  - faa
  - fee
- bar

  - boo
  - bee
  - bii

Now, in my theme I have one horizontal menu that shall *always* display

**foo | bar**

Below that, there's another horizontal menu which, when **foo** is clicked, should display:

**fii | faa | fee**

When **bar** is clicked, that same menu shall display:

**boo | bee | bii**

Only the sub-menus of the currently selected main menu (*foo/bar*) shall be displayed.

**How can this be achieved?**

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in at least two ways:

1) Via CSS. Use the appropriate class selectors (e.g. current-page-item, current-page-parent, current-page-ancestor) to display the appropriate sub-menu.

2) Separate calls to wp_list_pages(). The first call will have a depth=1 argument passed, and the second will determine the ID of the current parent page, and output accordingly, using the "child_of" argument, e.g.:

```
<?php
global $post;
$current_page_parent = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );

wp_list_pages( array(
     'title_li' => '',
     'child_of' => $current_page_parent,
     'depth' => '1' )
);
?>
```

There are probably other ways, as well.